# AppleScript - If document.getElementById value is null, enter value

Tags: javascript, webforms, applescript

First time asking a question, let me know if I'm doing this wrong. I have an AppleScript that takes values from a Numbers document, and enters them into various fields of a webform using `document.getElementById`.

It works flawlessly, but now I want to add a feature so that it will *only* fill in a value if that field in the webform is blank.

My idea for the code was going to be something like this:

```
if ("document.getElementById('something').value = null)
            execute javascript ("document.getElementById('something').value = '" & valueToFillIn & "'")
else
    move on
```

Can someone advise me on the best way to check if a `document.getElementById` value is `null`, and then how to proceed? Very much appreciated!

Comment: Your doing fine for a first-time poster. Welcome to StackOverflow! I made just a few minor formatting improvements. Some language syntax can best be marked as code, even in sentences (wrap in backticks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres a very simple alternative as well. Modify for your needs. I believe its well explained and obvious of what is going on in the script. The else statement is not required to "move on". Once the `if` statement is checked, the script moves on without needing the `else` unless you want to execute something else if that field has value.

```
-- Tested Here -> http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

set fieldValue to getInputById("dencoder") of me

if fieldValue is "" then
    inputByID("dencoder", "Im Allowed to Input Text Because You Were Empty") of me
else
    say "The Field Was Not Empty"
end if


-- Simple Handlers
-- Retrieve Value of elementById
to getInputById(theId)
    tell application "Safari"
    set output to do JavaScript "document.getElementById('" & theId & "').value;" in document 1
end tell
return output
end getInputById

-- Input My String to element by Id
to inputByID(theId, theValue)
    tell application "Safari"
    do JavaScript "  document.getElementById('" & theId & "').value ='" & theValue & "';" in document 1
end tell
end inputByID
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things you have to consider before use this snippet:

1- When this code will be triggered? Regularly in the click eventListener, like the example below:

2- Which value do you want to post? Please be more specific.

```
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", checkInputs);

function checkInputs() {
    if (document.getElementById("01").value == ""){
        var newValue = document.getElementById("02").value;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=newValue;
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/azwt542p/2/

*There are a few methods to get input textbox value straight (without wrapping the input element inside a form element):*

> These methods returns a collection of elements, so use [whole_number]
>   to get the desired occurrence, for first element use [0] and for
>   second one use 1 and so on...

**Alternative 1:**

> Use  `document.getElementsByClassName('class_name')[whole_number].value`
>   which returns a Live HTMLCollection
>
> Eg. `document.getElementsByClassName("searchField")[0].value`;if this is
>   the first textbox in your page.

**Alternative 2:**

> Use `document.getElementsByTagName('tag_name')[whole_number].value`
>   which also returns a live HTMLCollection
>
> Eg.  `document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;` ,if this is the
>   first textbox in your page.

**Alternative 3:**

> Use powerful  `document.querySelector('selector').value` which uses CSS
>   selector to select element
>
> Eg. `document.querySelector('#searchTxt').value;` selected by id
>   `document.querySelector('.searchField').value;` selected by class
>   `document.querySelector('input').value;` selected by tagname
>   `document.querySelector('[name="searchTxt"]').value;` selected by name

Comment: To be more specific, this AppleScript will be triggered using a hotkey while I have Numbers.app open. The value I want to post is plain text (string) and is held in a specific cell. The value is located in column 'C', and the row is whatever row I currently have selected. The AppleScript will then open Google Chrome to the page of the webform, and fill in the required field using the code I provided. Currently, the code just has the 'execute javascript' line and it works fine, but now I want the AppleScript to only fill in the field if it is currently empty.